# Multiple conditions not firing in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am having javascript function written to check if the dropdown value from an aspx page has value "Completed" or "Cancelled".if it is then check if the date and time is not null.
But the function never fires. the code is below.

```
function EnableValidator() {
    var drp = document.getElementById('<%=drpcallstatus.ClientID %>');
    var txt = drp.options[drp.selectedIndex].text;
    var dt = document.getElementById('<%=txtcompletedate.ClientID %>');
    var ct = document.getElementById('<%=txtcomptime.ClientID %>');



    if ((txt == "Completed" | txt=="Cancelled") && (dt===null | ct===null))  {

            alert("Please Enter the Completed Date and Time");

            return false;

    }
```

The function is called from asp.net button

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit"  OnClientClick="return EnableValidator()"  onclick="btnsubmit_Click" />
```

Comment: | isn't valid, use || instead for an 'or' operator.

Comment: can you share the rendered HTML for the select?

Comment: @jackJoe The Rendered HTML select is format <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$drpcallstatus" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_drpcallstatus"> <option selected="selected" value="Pending">Pending</option> <option value="Completed">Completed</option> <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option> <option value="On Hold">On Hold</option> <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option> </select> – Rohan 39 secs ago

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are not using the correct operator for your `OR`.

```
if ((txt == "Completed" || txt=="Cancelled") && (dt===null || ct===null))  {
  ...
}
```

Use double pipe characters `||` for an `OR` operator in a conditional expression.

Comment: This is *Javascript* and not *PHP* (you linked the PHP documentation), although the `OR` operator is the same :)

Comment: Thanks for respone. i tried that this too but it still does't fire. i used || instaed of '&&' then alert fires even if the condition doesn't match.i think the way the  condition is  written is wrong or what.

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
if ((txt == "Completed" || txt=="Cancelled") && (dt===null || ct===null))  {
            alert("Please Enter the Completed Date and Time");
            return false;
}
```

You have to use `||` for it works.